# Can't open ports on VM instances

Tags: google-compute-engine

I'm trying to open tcp and udp port 7774 on google cloud VM instance without results.
[image]

I'm sure that my server is using this network. For example, the ssh port is opened, rdp port also should be opened but i can't communicate with the server on this port, the same situation is with 7774 port, i have to setup something which needs this port to communicate, but i don't know how.
I also added rules to iptables:

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -d 0/0 -s 0/0 --dport 7774 -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -p udp -d 0/0 -s 0/0 --dport 7774 -j ACCEPT
Without any results.

Comment: Do you have a service listening on port 7774 on your instance? You can check that by running netstat -tulpn command.

Comment: Could you paste your iptables rules? Could you add the rules with the `-I` parameter instead of the `-A` parameter?